# How can we correctly determine if two floating point variables are equal?

Tags: math, floating-point, compare, computer-science

I'm doing a quiz and I wonder if I can correctly determine it. These are options:

```
See if a == b is true
Check if a - b == 0 is true
Check if ((a-b)*(a-b))/(a*a + b*b) is close to or is zero
Check a*b == a*a is true
None of the above
```

I tried to compare float and double values in C++ and I didn't succeed with any of the given formulas. I'd say "None of the above" but I don't know how it works in other languages. I read somewhere that in Java could be different but I would choose the last options as generally other answers are incorrect. What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't succeed"? What *exactly* did you try, what was the result, and why was the result not what you wanted?

Answer (score 4):

The floating-point comparison operation is “perfect” in that it returns true if and only if the tested relation is true. There are never any rounding errors. There is incorrect folklore that you cannot compare floating-point numbers or need to use some tolerance to compare them, but this is because earlier operations that prepare the operands to a comparison typically have rounding errors, similar to the way 7/3 rounds to 2 in integer arithmetic.

If your quiz is based on correct principles of floating-point arithmetic, then “See if `a == b` is true” is correct. Otherwise, the answer is unclear and the quiz is suspect.

Comment: Aside from `a,b` as infinity, how might `a - b == 0` fail?  With not the best rounding with small values or lack of infinity?

Comment: @chux: It can fail in IEEE-754 for ∞−∞→NaN as you note but not otherwise. It can fail in floating-point arithmetic without subnormals (a≠b but a−b is so small it must round to zero). It can fail in nonconforming implementations that flush subnormal results to zero. The NaN issue should suffice to disqualify it as the quiz answer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Here's a concrete example. Take single-precision floats `a = 8.414285e-37` and `b = 8.362857e-37`. Neither of these are subnormal. Their difference is `5.142788e-39`, which is a subnormal value, and thus can be rounded to zero if the system doesn't support subnormals. However, you are correct that excluding infinity, in a system that supports subnormals `a == b` and `a - b == 0` are logically equivalent.

Comment: @alias  Sorry my "With not the best rounding with small values" did not make clear that I had already considered that case.